# pssh and ssh-agent key forwarding via jump host

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying to connect to a number of hosts using pssh in combination with a jump host and ssh-agent key forwarding.

Unfortunately this fails quiet regular, but with different hosts failing on. So this is only an example which would look different next time:

```
 ~> pssh -h /tmp/hostfile -o /tmp/log  -e /tmp/error/ -v uname -a
[1] 13:51:18 [FAILURE]  host1 Exited with error code 255
[2] 13:51:19 [SUCCESS]  host2 
[3] 13:51:19 [SUCCESS]  host3 
[4] 13:51:19 [SUCCESS]  host4
[5] 13:51:19 [SUCCESS]  host5
[6] 13:51:19 [SUCCESS]  host6
[7] 13:51:19 [SUCCESS]  host7
….
[16] 13:51:19 [SUCCESS] host16
```

When having a deeper look, I'm getting

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

on the host that failed. This looks much like the ssh-agent keyforwarding via jump host did not work in this particular scenario.

Inside my ~.ssh/config it looks like this:

```
ForwardAgent yes

Host *.tld.foo
    User frlan
    ProxyCommand ssh tld-jump-host nc %h %p

Host tld-jump-host
    HostName myhost.example.com
    User frlan
    ProxyCommand none
```

Usually this is working. Now I'm wondering why starting at about 15 hosts sometime the key is not forwarded an dhow I can upgrade my configuration to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to connect to a number of hosts using pssh in combination with a jump host and ssh-agent key forwarding.

For connections using `ProxyCommand` you do not need any `ssh-agent` forwarding. All the authentication is done directly from your computer.

Manual page for `ssh_config` says

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used.

therefore the `Host tld-jump-host` block should be before `Host *.tld.foo` block, especially if the jump box has the same tld as the hosts behind it.

If you are connecting to many hosts behind this jump box, you might be triggering connection limit and the connections will get randomly rejected. You can try to avoid it by bumping the connection rate limit in jumpbox server (`MaxStartups` option in `sshd_config`), or multiplex the connections to the jump box by creating directory `~/.ssh/cm/` and adding the following to the jumbox block in `ssh_config`:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/cm/%C
ControlPersist 5m
```

Comment: I changed sorting of the options which did not solve the issue. Also ForwardAgent triggering did not change anything.

Comment: Probable issue is that you are connecting to the jumphost multiple times, which triggers connection rejection (too many connections -- you would be able to see such error in the server log). Try to use connection multiplexing (I will update the answer).

Comment: I did not see any error on jump host inside e.g. auth.log — but the controlmaster-configs did solve it (at least for tests I did).

Comment: It might be in verbose/debug logs ... I am not sure now. Clearly with control master you should get significantly better performance.

Comment: I will test it a little more. Meanwhile just +1 for the help